# CSS responsive works in IE and FF but not Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, reflow

I'm building a site here http://www.burnsoldparish.org/

I'm having problems getting the responsive mode to work correctly in Chrome.  It works in IE and FF (well the latest versions of them)

for some reason the flow doesn't work when you expand the menu that appears in responsive mode.  If you resize the screen you'll see the standard menu come up but it won't reflow properly in Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: place your relevant code here, we often don't see the website link...

Comment: Your link leads to a 404

Comment: sorry site had geographical blocking switched on.